# How to pre fill form with data using AJAX and Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

On my page I have some data shown coming from a SQL `database`. When I click edit behind the entry, I have a modal pop up.

In that modal I have a couple of input fields. What I want to do is have the data be filled into the fields.

I sadly find this very hard to get my head around, because I use AJAX and Jquery.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You should provide us with a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on what you have already done..

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[name=data1]').attr('value','test'); //when ajax is ready call this
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="data1" type="text">
```

You can use attr to alter the value of the input field.

Comment: or you could just use `.val('test')`, much easier.